# Assing item values to breeds using matrix .csv

Tags: csv, matrix, netlogo

I have a csv file with a matrix of cost transportation that looks like this on csv:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QrQU.png)

I have three breeds with the same name than the matrix data and I would like to assign one item to one breed. For example, the item Valencia with the breed Valencia to calculate the value of the distance but I dont have any idea. I am using the extension csv but I dont find any solution! I dont add the code becuase I dont even know how to start. Any ideas?